# How to change Enunciate class name with a custom String

Tags: rest, documentation, resteasy, enunciate

I am evaluating Enunciate to produce the documentation for a java rest api built with resteasy. How can I change the resource class name with a custom String?

The annotation @ResourceLabel can only be applied to methods. Any idea?

Thanks,
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

In Enunciate 1, you should be able to use [enunciate facets](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Facets-(Version-1)) to get what you want. Instead of grouping the API by resource class name, group it by a custom facet.

In Enunciate 2, the @ResourceLabel annotation applies to types in addition to methods and you should be able to use that.